# How to make ui automator viewer run in M1 macs?

Tags: android, apple-m1

I have been struggling for a while now. I am trying to run ui automator viewer on my m1 mac, but it seems that no matter what I try, I am not able to even see the GUI of ui automator viewer.

I am not experienced with these kind of stuffs, so is there anyone who are able to do it? Would you like to share how you did it?

Thank you!

What I tried :

1. I installed the latest android sdk, and I tried clicking on "uiautomatorviewer" under "/Users/{username}/Library/Android/sdk/tools/bin" and nothing opens.
2. Then, I tried the suggestion on https://github.com/android/android-test/issues/911#issuecomment-849389068. But I believe this is not my issue, as I am not even able to see anything pop up. I see no window.
3. Then, I tried running `/Users/{username}/Library/Android/sdk/tools/bin/uiautomatorviewer`, but I get this error

`SWT folder '/Users/enyihou/Library/Android/sdk/tools/lib/aarch64' does not exist. Please export ANDROID_SWT to point to the folder containing swt.jar for your platform.`

4. I tried creating the folder aarch64 and copied the swt.jar inside `/Users/{username}/Library/Android/sdk/tools/lib/x86` to the aarch64 folder.
   I now get this error :
   `Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine. Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.`
5. I tried. step 4 with the swt.jar file inside x86_64 folder, and from the latest swt.jar for arm version mac from the eclipse website
   https://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/downloads/drops4/R-4.27-202303020300/
   I still get the same error as in 4.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!
Thank you for reading.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem: ui automator viewer does not support running on arm64 version of java, so after following the steps above, you just need to switch to java 1.8, which is the x64 version of java, translated via Rosetta :

```
export JAVA_HOME=`/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.8.0_202`
```

And then you can run your app

```
/Users/<username>/Library/Android/sdk/tools/bin/uiautomatorviewer
```